# How to set fab icon tint to null programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, floating-action-button

I used the image on the fab button and the result is like this :

[image]

and set  `app:tint="@null"` for original image and the result is :

[image]

but what I want is... I want to set tint @null programmatically

or how to achieve the same result programmatically

Answer (score 2):

I would assume it would look something like this:

```
yourFabName.getDrawable().mutate().setTint(...the tint value you want goes here);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. here setTint() method takes int parameter but I have to set here null.. which is not possible .. then I used setTintList() method and Taaddaaaaa... I achieve the desired result... thanks again :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it